# Batch: How to append string in FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, append, concatenation

I'm having issues to append strings in FOR loop.

I want to create subfolders for each name stored in an array.
The subfolders belong to a folder with a name given by user.

For example, If I have the following names in my array:
 - Folder 1
 - Folder 2
 - Folder 3

I want to have the folders:

C:\MyFolder\Folder 1
 C:\MyFolder\Folder 2
 C:\MyFolder\Folder 3

As previous said, the "MyFolder" name is typed by user in the command line.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
@break off
@title Generate Billing Subfolders
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "batch_path=%~dp0"
SET "first_folder=01. Folder1"
SET "second_folder=02. Folder2"
SET "third_folder=03. Folder3"

:: Create the new Working Data folder
SET /p new_folder_name= Enter Directory Name: 
SET "full_path=%batch_path%%new_folder_name%"

ECHO Working...

IF NOT EXIST ("%full_path%") (
  MKDIR %new_folder_name%
  IF "!errorlevel!" EQU "0" (
    ECHO Folder created successfully.
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO Error while creating folder.
  )
) ELSE (
  ECHO Folder already exists.
)

SET "folders_list="%first_folder%" "%second_folder%" "%third_folder%""


FOR %%f in (%folders_list%) DO (
    :: Displays the folder name in array correctly
    ECHO %%f 
    :: Displays ECHO is off. Why?
    CALL SET "updated_full_path=%full_path%\%%f"
    ECHO %updated_full_path%
    PAUSE


)
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have [enabled delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

....


FOR %%f in (%folders_list%) DO (
    :: Displays the folder name in array correctly
    ECHO %%f 
    :: Displays ECHO is off. Why?
    SET "updated_full_path=!full_path!\%%f"
    ECHO !updated_full_path!
    PAUSE


)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not understanding the purpose of EnableDelayedExpansion and using "!...!". I will update the code with the answer of my question following your indications.